# Uniform Łojasiewicz constant in 2D

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, polynomials, real-algebraic-geometry

[Łojasiewicz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%81ojasiewicz_inequality) is a classical result in real algebraic geometry. In particular, for any given polynomial $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ there is some $C>0$ and some $\alpha>0$ such that for all $|x|<1$ we have
$$
\mathrm{dist}(x,Z(f))^\alpha\leq C|f(x)|,
$$
where $Z(f)$ denotes the zero set of $f$. There has been abundant reseach into the optimal exponent $\alpha$, and in the 2D case there is an elementary paper by Kuo (1974):

https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02566729.pdf

for an explicit computation of the exponent $\alpha$.

However, I was wondering if there is a uniform estimate (in terms of the degree of $f$) of the constant $C$, even in 2D. Of course this question would make no sense if the coefficients of $f$ can be arbitrarily small; for this reason I require that at least one coefficient of $f$ has absolute value bounded below by 1.